# How to use weights of embedding layers as alternative feature for categorical feature

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, categorical-data, embedding

I am working on categorical data that i want to use weight of embedding layers to enhance the quality of information.

After training model:

the weight of one categorical feature looks like as below:

```
weights = model.get_layer('embedding1').get_weights()
pd.DataFrame(weights[0],columns = ['item_name_eb1','item_name_eb2','item_name_eb3'])

    item_name_eb1   item_name_eb2   item_name_eb3
0   0.023240    -0.034689   0.015933
1   -0.038246   0.038206    0.023874
2   0.042594    0.024021    0.045987
3   -0.022057   -0.001511   -0.032946
4   0.034829    -0.032142   0.030436
... ... ... ...
21077   -0.015355   -0.005613   -0.003528
21078   0.045894    -0.008100   0.004058
21079   -0.005017   0.036867    -0.020634
21080   0.039784    -0.010046   -0.008047
21081   -0.017162   -0.029755   -0.049114
```

this is embedded layers for this categorical feature:

```
df['item_name']
0                                          ЯВЛЕНИЕ 2012 (BD)
1                   DEEP PURPLE  The House Of Blue Light  LP
2                   DEEP PURPLE  The House Of Blue Light  LP
3                   DEEP PURPLE  Who Do You Think We Are  LP
4                    DEEP PURPLE 30 Very Best Of 2CD (Фирм.)
                                 ...                        
2935844                     V/A Nu Jazz Selection (digipack)
2935845               V/A The Golden Jazz Collection  1  2CD
2935846                         V/A The Best Of The 3 Tenors
2935847    V/A Relax Collection  Planet MP3 (mp3-CD) (jewel)
2935848               V/A The Golden Jazz Collection  1  2CD
Name: item_name, Length: 2935849, dtype: object
```

The question is I want to add back weight of embedding layers to replace this categorical.

Thanks in advance for any helps.

Comment: Do you want to map the categories in df['item_name'] with the trained numerical embedding? is it correct?

Comment: yes, I want to map df['item_name'] back with trained numerical embedding.

Comment: U can simply do this by creating a sub-model that maps and extracts the embeddings

Comment: I thought there are attribute or something that can do this mapping. I'm thinking to use dict(index, df['item_name'].nunique()) and then mapping, but there is different in total number of unique value.  I am not quite sure how you create sub-model, mean you train again or something???

Comment: Dear Marco Cerliani, I change size of vocabulary and did it, thanks for your suggestion.